# PostgreSQL, allow to filter by not existing fields

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm using a PostgreSQL with a Go driver. Sometimes I need to query not existing fields, just to check - maybe something exists in a DB. Before querying I can't tell whether that field exists. Example:

```sql
where size=10 or length=10
```

By default I get an error `column "length" does not exist`, however, the `size` column could exist and I could get some results.

Is it possible to handle such cases to return what is possible?

---

**EDIT:**

Yes, I could get all the existing columns first. But the initial queries can be rather complex and not created by me directly, I can only modify them.

That means the query can be simple like the previous example and can be much more complex like this:

```sql
WHERE size=10 OR (length=10 AND n='example') OR (c BETWEEN 1 and 5 AND p='Mars')
```

If missing columns are `length` and `c` - does that mean I have to parse the SQL, split it by `OR` (or other operators), check every part of the query, then remove any part with missing columns - and in the end to generate a new SQL query?

Any easier way?

Comment: What should the result be if the column doesn't exist? No rows or all rows?

Comment: It might be not the best idea, but can you substitute the original table name with a subquery and fake all non exists columns in that subquery along with the actual data? Like this: 

`select * from (select 10 as length, 'example' as n, 'Mars' as p, size, whatever from original_table)  as table_alias WHERE length = 10 or  n='example' OR p='Mars'`

All your filters will remain as before

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , if the column doesn't exist you can drop related `AND` group because any correct results will be impossible. Other `OR` groups still should be executed, because all `OR` parts logically are independent

Comment: @Illia, can you show a full example for my 2'nd query? `length` and `c` does not exist

Comment: `select * from (select 10 as length, 'example' as n, 'Mars' as p, size, 2 as c from original_table)  as table_alias WHERE size=10 OR (length=10 AND n='example') OR (c BETWEEN 1 and 5 AND p='Mars')`

Comment: @Alexey did it work for you?

Comment: @Illia, `as is` it won't work for me, as `length=10` query and others will always return `true`, however it is incorrect for the current DB, so many returned results will be false-positive. I'm thinking about faking "for sure" incorrect values - the opposite variant. But haven't implemented generating new SQL yet

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do what you want, except for constructing an SQL string from the list of available columns, which can be got by querying `information_schema.columns`.

SQL statements are parsed before they are executed, and there is no conditional compilation or no short-circuiting, so you get an error if a non-existing column is referenced.

Comment: I've added more info the question

Comment: I have added more to the answer. You cannot get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to check within information schema first

"select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name ='table_name';"

And then based on result do query

Comment: I've added more info the question

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you get a list of columns that are in the table first? Like this

```
select column_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'table_name' and (column_name = 'size' or column_name = 'length');
```

The result will be the columns that exist.

Comment: I've added more info the question